# Postgres Cursor With Hold

Tags: database, postgresql, cursor

Cursor With Hold use database resources when fetching lot of data.

What resources do they use? How much?
Does setting cursor_tuple_fraction to 1 have an impact on resources used?

I want to fetch all rows of a table but about a 1000 rows at one time..

Answer (score 0):

Cursors WITH HOLD use physical disk space, they are stored in temporary files. The amount of space require depends on your query and your data, you can make a (rough) estimation multiplying the expected number of rows times the size of a single row. Setting cursor_tuple_fraction to 1 doesn't have any impact on the amount of space used, but it does impact the time it takes to create the cursor [SOURCE](https://demo.pganalyze.com/databases/6/config/cursor_tuple_fraction).

Read [PostgreSQL Documentation: DELARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-declare.html)